# How do I place a group of variables in a specific section in gcc, is there anything like #pragma default_variable_attributes available with arm

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

The below link 
https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/linker/how-do-i-place-a-group-of-functions-or-variables-in-a-specific-section/
explains how a group of variables can be placed in a specific section, this is with IAR arm linker.

Pasting the example (for which i want a gcc equivalent) from the link here

```
/* Place following data in section MY_DATA */
#pragma default_variable_attributes = @ "MY_DATA"

int data1;
int data2;

/* Stop placing data in section MY_DATA */
#pragma default_variable_attributes =
```

In gcc do we have any such feature, which helps me to define in the source code how the variables can be place contiguously.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With gcc you use the compiler's `__attribute__` extension of the declarator syntax, e.g.

```
int my_global_1 __attribute__ ((section ("MyData"))) = 0;
int my_global_2 __attribute__ ((section ("MyData"))) = 0;

__attribute__ ((section ("MyFuncs"))) int foo(int i) 
{
    return i * i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, i had tried this earlier ... but had done a mistake last time, one of the variable was mentioned as const and this resulted in some error. Your answer helped me to revisit the declaration.