# How do I convert part of the code for ICCARM to GNUC?

Tags: gcc, iar

I had a piece of code in IAR.

```
#if defined (__ICCARM__)
#define __vectors   __root const uVectorEntry __vector_table[] @ ".intvec"
#define __stack     { .ui32Ptr = (uint32_t)Stack + sizeof(Stack) }
typedef union
{
  void (*Handler)(void);
  uint32_t ui32Ptr;

} uVectorEntry;
#endif
```

It needs to be redone for GCC.

Everything that after defining along the way is also independent of the compiler.
Perhaps only 1 line `#define __vectors   __root const uVectorEntry __vector_table[] @ ".intvec"` requires a reaction.

This is the startap file for stm32f103c8t6 (Cortex-M3).
More precisely a small piece of it.
So `__vector_table[]` must have 59 elemehts, and it is interrupt vector table.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638115/how-do-i-place-a-group-of-variables-in-a-specific-section-in-gcc-is-there-anyth, it may answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

`__vectors` is likely used in vector table definition in the form `__vectors = { /* vector table elements */ };`. Macro definition is as follows:

- `const uVectorEntry __vector_table[]` is standard C declaration for a const table.
- `__root` is an attribute that specifies that this object must not be removed by the compiler or linker even if it might seem unused.
- `@ ".intvec"` specifies that `__vector_table` should be placed in `.intvec` section by the linker.

`__stack` is likely used in the vector table to have the end address of stack, to initialize stack pointer at boot time.

To put it shortly, all non-standard parts are there to ensure that vector table is in correct location and is not removed.

Comment: Thank you, yore are right. But this problem is no longer relevant, this startup file did not do anything so supernatural, I can use the default startup. I thought it might be needed for a further piece of code, but it turned out that the embarrassing trick (translating the interrupt vector table into RAM) does not depend on the startup.