# Bunch of variables in a particular data section

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, arm

I need to locate a bunch of variables in a particular data section.

I'm using `__attribute__((section("name")))` to handle it, so my code is something like:

```
#define DATA ".ARM.__at_0x0800000"

int a __attribute__((section(DATA)));
int b;
int c;
```

The problem is that variables `b` and `c` does not follow the position of the variable `a` in memory.

How can I handle this without placing an `__attribute__((section("name")))` to each variable?

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I place a group of variables in a specific section in gcc, is there anything like #pragma default\_variable\_attributes available with arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638115/how-do-i-place-a-group-of-variables-in-a-specific-section-in-gcc-is-there-anyth)

Comment: If you are up to hardcoded memory addresses than use pointers `int* ptr_a = (int*) 0x0800000; int* ptr_b = (int*) 0x0800004; *ptr_a = 5 /* write '5' to address '0x0800000' */; *ptr_b = 0x123 /* write '0x123' to address '0x0800004' */;` Otherwise you need to create separate section for each variable...